# How to have an alert and document.getElementById().focus() in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

How do I have these `alert('Please input your firstname.'); document.getElementById ("firstname").focus();` inside my ajax code where the error message shows? Because I have it in text in my webpage but I want it to be an alert and focus on the input id like the one javascript. How do I do it here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function()
{
     $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            firstname: {
            required: true
            },
            lastname: {
            required: true
            },

       },
       messages:
       {
            firstname:"Please input your firstname.",
            lastname:"Please input your lastname.",     

       },
       submitHandler: submitForm    
       });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you read a comic and watch Avengers at the same time? -You can't have two elements on focus at the same time.

Comment: The function that is called on submit is not even part of this code you have just given us.

Comment: What I am trying to do is replace `firstname:"Please input your firstname."` (which gives me a text as the error message) into `firstname:alert('Please input your firstname.'); document.getElementById ("firstname").focus();` instead as the error message, but I know this is wrong. So I was wondering how it is done? @BekimBacaj

Comment: I recommend you don't do it. Because, when user edit input tag, validate plugin automatically removes and puts error message. Alerting it would be annoying

Comment: @EmVee - that's just a string value that the `submitForm` function utilizes, not actual lines of logic that do anything. Whatever you want to do as custom logic on submit, it will be done from that function, which you have not included here.

Comment: Okay then, I'll have another way to make the error obvious then. Thanks for the tip! @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Comment: what do u mean "from that function" ? @BryanGrezeszak